# How do I pass a "list" argument to an Umbraco macro?

Tags: umbraco

I have an Umbraco macro that I'd like to pass a "list" argument to — i.e. I have multiple elements that I'm transforming with XSLT, and I'd like to transform some of them in a "special" way.

Ideally I'd like to try something like this:

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="DoStuff" runat="server">
    <styleThisSpecially>NameOfElement1</styleThisSpecially>
    <styleThisSpecially>NameOfElement2</styleThisSpecially>
</umbraco:Macro>
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work — the "styleThisSpecially" elements are not recognised.

Workarounds I can think of are:

1. passing through arguments like "styleThisSpecially1", "styleThisSpecially2", "styleThisSpecially3", ...
2. passing through my argument as a comma separated list like "styleThisSpecially='val1,val2,val3'"

...but neither of these options seem very "neat". I tried using multiple "styleThisSpecially" attributes on the umbraco:Macro element, but that caused an error ("the tag contains duplicate 'expandBox' attributes").

Is there a clean and tidy way to do this?

Comment: "and I'd like to transform some of them in a "special" way" Transforming with a different `mode` is out of question?

Comment: @Flack: That's a pretty good idea. The macro is going through all of the current pages subpages, and styling a link to most of them in one way and then styling the "important" ones (as defined by the customer) in another way (maybe something like adding a "highlight" class &mdash; that's not really what's happening but you get the point). I thought I would just pass a list of the "special" nodes through as an argument. But, now I think I'll just add an attribute to the "special" subpages and have the XSLT treat them differently. It should actually be much cleaner.

Comment: I'd still be interested in knowing if there's a way to pass a "list" of arguments through to an Umbraco macro, but for now I think my original problem is solved in a neat way. Thanks for the idea Flack.

Comment: If this is specific  Umbraco question, then it's not about XSLT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're starting at "point X" and working out all the elements and you want to pass them all to the macro as a list.
Probably a neater solution is either:
1. Let the page not only find the elements, but also iterate these and pass them one at a time to the macro for "rendering/processing/whatever"
2. Pass "point X" to the macro and let the macro work out what the elements are?

Doesn't really answer the question of whether you can pass a list of elements to a macro, but I think perhaps (certainly if you're working in XSLT) this is rarely something you'd want to do.